# Let $f_X(x)=k\sin x,0≤x≤π$. Find $P(X ≥ π/3)$.

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $f_X(x)=k\sin x,0≤x≤π$.

- (a) Find $k$ so $f_X$ is a probability density function.
  I got $k = -1/2$
- (b) Find $P(π/3≤X ≤π/2)$.
  I got $1/4$
- (c) Find $P(X ≥ π/3)$.
  I stuck here, this function is divergent right?
- (d) Sketch the graph of $f_X$ and shade the area represented by the
  probability in
- (e) Find $F_X$ and sketch its graph.

Comment: HI, I just added what I having problem with. Thank you!

Comment: Have you heard about LaTeX?

Comment: Just use the fact if $f(x)$ is pdf then its integral should be 1 within your limits $0 to \pi$..

Comment: @user312254 hi, what is pdf? Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @MikeJones PDF abbreviates probability density function.

Comment: For future reference, use proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, show your work, not just your numeric answer, so that others can proofread it, and not have to do it from scratch. Always include your thoughts and work in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Try again; since you want a density, then
$$\int_0^{\pi}k\sin x\,dx = 1.$$
You got the wrong $k$.

(b) Since you got (a) wrong, I assume this is wrong too. Should be easy to fix.

(c) No, they told you that $0\leq x\leq \pi$. Hence
$$P(X\geq \pi/3) = \int_{\pi/3}^\pi f_X(x)\,dx.$$

(d),(e) This should not be too bad.

Comment: No problem. Consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.